# How to approach ordinary differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'' -4y' + 4y=0$$

My attempt:

We solve $r^2e^{rx}-4re^{rx}+e^{rx}=0$ for $r$, this gives $r=2$

Then the solution is: $y=c_1e^{2x}$

But the solution given is $y=c_1e^{2x}+c_2xe^{2x}$.

I wonder where the $x$ in $c_2xe^{2x}$ comes from, why is it different?

Comment: If you write and solve the equation for r correctly, you will find that it's a repeated root and r=2, just as the answer says

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have changed it and edited the post for a follow up question.

Comment: @ ZohaadFazal, please see the answer given by Dave. If you encountered this equation, you should have been given the theory necessary to understand how they are solved. If not, please find some textbook on ODE's. Also, you have not fixed your post completely, there's some mistakes left.

Comment: Thank you, I (hopefully) have fixed them now. I will find a textbook on ODE's.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the characteristic polynomial for this equation is $r^2-4r+4=(r-2)^2$ which has a double root at $r=2$ (not $r=-2$). Since this is an order $2$ equation, there are two linearly independent solutions, so you cannot just have the solution $y_1=c_1e^{2x}$. The other solution is then $y_2=c_2xe^{2x}$. Indeed, if there is a repeated root in an ordinary differential equation with multiplicity $n$, then there are solutions $p(x)e^{rx}$ where $p$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$. In this case, $r=2$ is a root of multiplicity $2$, so the polynomial $p(x)$ has degree one.